# Jenkins Pipeline using fastlane how to invoke fetch_program_license_agreement_messages

Tags: jenkins, mobile, fastlane

I want to do exactly this:
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fastlane/2.162.0/Spaceship/Client#fetch_program_license_agreement_messages-instance_method

But alas I have inheritted a Jenkins fastlane build setup that I don't understand, and I don't have the faintest idea how to invoke that method :(

I currently have a `.JenkinsFile`, which calls: `bundle exec fastlane build_ios --verbose`, which points to a `FastLane` file, which calls a variety of the actions listed on here:
https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/

Is calling that Spaceship.Client method something that I can do? And if so, how?